# python manage.py runserver is not finding temba settings file

Tags: python, django

I'm a python, temba noob, so please be patient. I've found other posts similar to this, but none have resolved my issue.

I'm installing Rapidpro on Ubuntu 15.04. It requires django and temba.

When I run `python manage.py runserver` I get:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 9, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/osboxes/dev/projects/rapidpro/rapidpro/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/osboxes/dev/projects/rapidpro/rapidpro/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/osboxes/dev/projects/rapidpro/rapidpro/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/osboxes/dev/projects/rapidpro/rapidpro/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/osboxes/dev/projects/rapidpro/rapidpro/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 98, in __init__
    % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e)
ImportError: Could not import settings 'temba.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): Could not import settings 'temba.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named pytz
```

I'm pretty sure my folder structure is good:

```
(env)osboxes@osboxes:~/dev/projects/rapidpro/rapidpro$ ls temba/settings.*
temba/settings.py  temba/settings.pyc  temba/settings.py.dev
```

And finally, here's my manage.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "temba.settings")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I'm running manage.py from its folder. This is driving me crazy (crazier?).

Any ideas?  TIA!

Comment: have you added temba to your installed_apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't read to the end of the traceback. It's not having trouble finding the settings file; it is trying to load a dependency, pytz, which you have not installed.

Comment: Ha - yeah, I guess I need to read the whole paragraph, even the fine print. I'm getting another error, but I'm at least past this one. Gimme a few mins and I'll probably mark this as the answer.  :-)  Thanks, Daniel!